# How to test this my functions?

Tags: java, junit

a want to test this function. Can you please write a test for one of those methods? I already read about JUnit testing but i really have no clue how to test this.

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Override
    public void render(Screen screen)
    {
        int xTile = playerLook[0];
        int yTile = playerLook[1];

        int walkingSpeed = 4;
        int flipTop = (numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1;
        int flipBottom = (numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1;

        if (movingDir == 1) {
            xTile += 2;
        }
        else if (movingDir > 1) {
            xTile += 4 + ((numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1) * 2;
            flipTop = (movingDir - 1) % 2;
        }

        int modifier = 8 * scale;
        int xOffset = x - modifier / 2;
        int yOffset = y - modifier / 2 - 4;

        if (isSwimming) {
            int waterColor = 0;
            yOffset += 4;
            if (tickCount % 60 < 15) {
                waterColor = Colors.get(-1, -1, 225, -1);
            } else if ((15 <= tickCount % 60) && (tickCount % 60 < 30)) {
                yOffset -= 1;
                waterColor = Colors.get(-1, 225, 115, -1);
            } else if ((30 <= tickCount % 60) && (tickCount % 60 < 45)) {
                waterColor = Colors.get(-1, 115, -1, 225);
            } else {
                yOffset -= 1;
                waterColor = Colors.get(-1, 225, 115, -1);
            }

            screen.render(xOffset, yOffset + 3, 0 + 27 * MAP_TILE_SIZE, waterColor, 0x00, 1);
            screen.render(xOffset + 8, yOffset + 3, 0 + 27 * MAP_TILE_SIZE, waterColor, 0x01, 1);
        }

        screen.render(xOffset + (modifier * flipTop), yOffset, xTile + yTile * MAP_TILE_SIZE, color, flipTop, scale);
        screen.render(xOffset + modifier - (modifier * flipTop), yOffset, (xTile + 1) + yTile * MAP_TILE_SIZE, color, flipTop, scale);

        if (!isSwimming) {
            screen.render(xOffset + (modifier * flipBottom), yOffset + modifier, xTile + (yTile + 1) * MAP_TILE_SIZE, color, flipBottom, scale);
            screen.render(xOffset + modifier - (modifier * flipBottom), yOffset + modifier, (xTile + 1) + (yTile + 1) * MAP_TILE_SIZE, color, flipBottom, scale);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasCollided(int xa, int ya)
    {
        int xMin = 0;
        int xMax = 7;
        int yMin = 3;
        int yMax = 7;

        for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, x, yMin)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, x, yMax)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int y = yMin; y < yMax; y++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, xMin, y)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int y = yMin; y < yMax; y++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, xMax, y)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

would really appreciate some help.

Thank you guys

Comment: *Can you please write a test for one of those methods* **NO**. SO is not a free coding service

Comment: Testing large methods is really hard (hence why some people write tests first). You could extract a very small chunk of this and try testing it on its own first.

Comment: Okay, can I test little bit smaller chunk of this?public class Creatures
{
    /**
     * List of all in-game creatures.
     */
    public ArrayList<Creature> creatures = new ArrayList<>();
    
    /**
     * Initializes database of all in-game creatures and adds them into a list.
     */
    public Creatures()
    {
        creatures.add(new Creature("Sweet Roll", 20, 10, 5, 1, "resources/npc/sweet-roll.png"));
    }